# When trying to insert data into a sqlite3 table from python, only empty fields appear

Tags: python

I have a problem, I am trying to make a CRUD using SQL application and I find myself in the user registration window, I connect to the database and insert the data into the fields, here is my code:

```
class Registro(Login):
    def __init__(self):
        
        Login.__init__(self)
    
        self.boton2 = Button(self.vent, text='Registrar', font=('calibri', 12), command=self.action_register).place(x=80, y= 205)

    def action_register(self):

        name = **self.name.get()** 
        psword = **self.password.get()**

        conn = sql.connect("database.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO usuarios (NOMBRE,PASS) VALUES ('"+name+"', '"+psword+"');")

        if cursor.fetchall():
            self.message = Label(self.vent, text='¡Registered succefully!', font=('calibri', 14),fg='Red').place(x=55, y=140)
            conn.commit()
        else:
            self.message2 = Label(self.vent, text='¡Error Register!', font=('calibri', 13), fg='Red').place(x=60, y=140)
        
        conn.close()
```

the `self.name.get()` and `self.password.get()` variables come from an `Entry` which receives a `StringVar()`

```
self.name = StringVar()
self.password = StringVar()

self.username_input = Entry(self.vent, textvariable=self.name).place(x=70, y=69)
self.password_input = Entry(self.vent, textvariable=self.password).place(x=90, y=104)
```

I expected that the data entered in the Entry would be read, saved and written into the database, with the condition "if cursor.fetchall()" I was in charge of validating that if it is met, write the data in the database and perform the commit, and if not, don't write anything and don't make the commit, the thing is that the condition "if cursor.fetchall()" is never met, I'm lost and I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Don't use concatenation to add variables to the SQL. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python

Comment: You can't use `cursor.fetchall()` for an `INSERT` query.

Comment: If there's a problem with the insert, an exception will be raised. You can use `try/except` to detect this.

Answer (score 0):

`cursor.fetchall()` doesn't return anything for `INSERT` queries, so you're never calling `conn.commit()`. If you want to know if anything was inserted, check `cursor.rowcount`. And use `try/except` to detect an error.

```
    def action_register(self):

        name = self.name.get()
        psword = self.password.get()

        conn = sql.connect("database.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        try:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO usuarios (NOMBRE,PASS) VALUES (?, ?);", (name, psword))

            if cursor.rowcount:
                self.message = Label(self.vent, text='¡Registered succefully!', font=('calibri', 14),fg='Red').place(x=55, y=140)
                conn.commit()
            else:
                self.message2 = Label(self.vent, text='¡Error Register!', font=('calibri', 13), fg='Red').place(x=60, y=140)
        except:
            self.message2 = Label(self.vent, text='¡Error Register!', font=('calibri', 13), fg='Red').place(x=60, y=140)
        
        conn.close()
```

Comment: I have tried it and it still doesn't work, I am also grateful for your help, I have to study SQL better

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Does it say something was inserted when it wasn't?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?